# how does flask get the value back from session cookies?

Tags: python, cookies, hash, flask

I was looking at a cookie set through the session object in flask and it was just a hash (or it looked like it was just a hash). The value I set for the cookie was nowhere to be found but flask could get the value back.

I thought you had to store the value in the cookie alongside the hash (and then have a SECRET in your app to mix with the value for the hash), otherwise I don't know how you'd get your value back.

I thought maybe they hash the secret and the value and then encode it for extra obfuscation or something along those lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cookie value contains *compressed and serialised data*.

Flask does this to the data stored in the cookie:

- Python data is serialised using (a customised form of) JSON.
- The serialisation is cryptographically signed to ensure integrity
- The signature plus serialisation is compressed (unless the compressed data would be *larger* than the uncompressed version) and base64 encoded.

On reading the cookie Flask only has to:

- Decompress the data
- Re-calculate the signature and validate it against the included signature
- Load the serialised data back to Python objects.

Most of this is taken care of by [`itsdangerous`](http://pythonhosted.org/itsdangerous/). The JSON encoding and decoding is handled by the [Flask `session` module](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/sessions.py).

Until recently, `pickle` was used to do the serialisation but that has security risks if the server-side secret was ever stolen. See [*Better Client-side sessions*](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/51/).